# Alerting Users of "FrameBusters"

Tags: website-design, web-app, interaction-design

I'm currently developing a web app that uses iframes that contain other people's sites (Think StumbleUpon). Some sites contain "Framebuster' though, these busters redirect my app to the site that the frame was containing.

This in-turn "kicks" users off my app, what would be a good way to alert users of this?

Would a "Sorry, [InsertSiteName] does not support this webpage, you are now being redirected" pop-up suffice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Though I generally dislike the kind of frames you're talking about, it might be better to keep the person's sense of control over what is happening. A message like "[Site Name] cannot be loaded in [Your App's Name]. Launch site in a new window? [Yes] [No]"

Comment: Definitely give them the _choice_, especially since the user has left your site you have given up all control; for all you know the next site may practically disable the browser's back functionality and the user could be stuck!